# Text anlaysis in r

Tags: r, comparison, grepl

In Base r how do I get

- Ref2 - the first 2 initials of the Ref, e.g. AC12 = AC, AL34 = AL
- Street2 - the first initial of each Street e.g. Abbey Court =
  AC, Albert Gardens = AG.
- compare Ref2 & Street2 to see if same or not
- then only use those that are not the same for further
  calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
> substr(Ref2,1,2) ==gsub("[a-z| ]","",Street2)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

You can use that logical vector to remove the `FALSE` values from your original data.
The code works by only taking the first two characters from `Ref2` and removing all lowercase characters + spaces from `Street2`.
**Data**

```
Ref2 = c("AC12","AL34")
Street2=c("Abbey Court","Albert Gardens")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Good idea on the lowercase characters.

Comment: This doesn't look like it would be exactly right because it is taking the first two letters of the street name, not the first letter of each word in the street name?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an option for anybody who wants to extract the first letter of each word where case is not consistent or the whole word is the same case.

This also includes filtering the table for continued use (using data.table).

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

data_example <- data.table(Ref2 = c("AC12", "AL34", "AG34"), 
                           Street = c("Abbey Court", "Albert gardens", "albert gardens"))

data_example <- data_example[tolower(str_extract(Ref2, "^.{2}")) == tolower(paste0(str_extract(Street, "^."), str_extract(Street, "(?<=\\s).")))]
```

```
> View(data_example)
> data_example
   Ref2         Street
1: AC12    Abbey Court
2: AG34 albert gardens
```